# Mongoose projection to filter list not working, but native does

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, find, projection

I'm trying to use the following find query to find a list of objects which are related to a "work" object with a specific ID, then return all "form" elements which aren't set to inactive (active = false).

This works perfectly using the mongo shell locally, or [testing on mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/EjHHpWx05Pg). But I can't figure out how to get mongoose to play nice and return the results I expect, I always get an empty array.

I don't understand why it would work perfectly find natively, but not via mongoose. There must be some kind of issue or peculiarity I'm not finding in the docs. My mongodb version is 5.0.5 and my mongoose version is 6.1.5.

Mongo find query I'm trying to use:

```
db.objects.find({
  "work": ObjectId("61d50a22eed3f421dc33a220")
},
{
  "form": {
    "$filter": {
      "input": "$form",
      "as": "form",
      "cond": {
        "$ne": [
          "$$form.active",
          false
        ]
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Mongoose code with Projection (not working, returning []):

```
export const getWIObjects = async (workID: string) => {
  const objs = await ObjectModel.find({
    work: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(workID),
  }).select({
    form: {
      $filter: {
        input: "$form",
        as: "form",
        cond: {
          $ne: ["$$form.active", false],
        },
      },
    },
  });
  return objs;
};
```

Mongoose code WITHOUT projection (returning data, but will include inactive fields):

```
export const getWIObjects = async (workID: string) => {
  const objs = await ObjectModel.find({
    work: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(workID),
  });
  return objs;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the following with MongoDB v5.0.6 and Mongoose v6.2.4, and the query returns results with the expected *projection*.

```
const projectn = 
    {
        form: {
            $filter: {
                input: "$form",
                as: "f",
                cond: {
                    $ne: [ "$$f.active", false ]
                }
            }
        }
    };
const filter = { }; // substitute your filter
const result = await MyModel.find(filter, projectn);
```

The following query (with different syntax) also returned the same result.

```
const result = await MyModel.find(filter).select(projectn);
```

**NOTE**: This projection syntax using aggregation operators requires at least MongoDB v4.4.

Comment: I thought that's what I had already been doing, so I'm not sure why it's now working when it previously wasn't after deleting what I had and re-implementing what you put here... But I'll take the win, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you have written in the **Mongoose code with Projection** is actually returning documents.

I think why you are getting an empty array **[]**, because you are probably querying an invalid workID that is not in the collection.

Please check the workID you are querying in the find method.

[image]

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately that's not the case. I am querying an existing document. In my final program, if I remove the projection component it works perfectly (but includes inactive fields in the results). The query works 100% correctly within mongo CLI directly.

Answer (score 0):

try using aggregation for this

```
const objs = await ObjectModel.aggregate([
    {
        '$match': {
            work: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(workID),
            "form.active": false
        }
    }, {
        '$project': {
            form: {
                $filter: {
                    input: "$form",
                    as: "f",
                    cond: {
                        $ne: ["$$f.active", false],
                    },
                },
            },
        }
    }
])
```

include form.active key in match also as it will lessen the number of documents after match query only

Comment: Hi Smriti,
I'll give it a shot later, but can you explain why aggregation would work when projection wouldn't within Mongoose? As I said, my query works 100% correctly if I run it through the mongo CLI directly and I expect mongoose and native CLI to have the same capabilities.

Comment: try checking your mongoose version as filter in project is supported on mongodb version 4.4 [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/]

according to mongoose documentation  [https://mongoosejs.com/docs/compatibility.html] your mongoose version should be ^5.10.0

Comment: Hi there, yep, if you check my question I listed the version of mongodb and mongoose. My mongodb version is 5.0.5 and my mongoose version is 6.1.5. I actually uninstalled both and installed the latest version to ensure there wasn't a version gap issue.

Comment: from the mongoose select documentation [https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select] it seems that filter in select is currently not supported .

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm clearly missing something... I don't see anything that states anything of the kind on that page or anywhere else I read through the documentation. I'm pretty sure I've read this thing from top to bottom twice now. Can you provide some key phrase I can CTRL+F to read up on it?

Comment: did you tried [this] (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-select) .  if not working you can try searching for Query.prototype.select(). from documentation it states that only object / array[string]/  string. in case of  object it shows a example in their example

Comment: Yep, I saw that... It does not indicate that selective projection isn't supported though... The example they show is a standard mongodb projection pattern which seems to indicate any standard pattern should be gtg.

Comment: I was finally able to test using aggregation - It results in nothing being returned in the same way as using .select.