# MongoDB - How to filter document objects within array?

Tags: mongodb

I have a problem with filtering fields(objects) from my document using `find` function.

Here is my `db.collection.find(..)` document:

```
{
  "_id": BinData(3, "Uz+QwtoVMt7hjpqMrLxVhQ=="),
  "name": "jeorge",
  "permissions": [
    {
      "key": "group.staff",
      "value": true,
      "context": [
        { "key": "server", "value": "test" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "key": "group.tester",
      "value": true,
      "context": [
        { "key": "server", "value": "test" }
      ]
    },
    {
      "key": "test.test",
      "value": true
    },
    {
      "key": "group.default",
      "value": true
    },
    {
      "key": "group.helper",
      "value": true
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I filter my document in two ways?

a) Display only fields with nested `context` object.

b) Display only fields, which hasn't got nested `context` objects.

Also I need to check if parent's object property `key` contains string "**group**" as value (If not - skip it).

For situation `b`, I have tried this function, but it prints result with only the first matched element (based on mongodb's documentation).

```
db.collection.find(
{
    "_id": BinData(3, "Uz+QwtoVMt7hjpqMrLxVhQ==")
},
{
    "permissions": {
        $elemMatch: {
            "key": {
                $regex: "group",
            },
            "value": true
        }
    }
}
);
```

Is it possible by single query? Thanks!

Comment: Clarity:  You are asking for a single query that returns field `permissions` both with *and without* nested `context` objects?  That is all objects; no filtering necessary.  
?
Second:   the parent key contains `group`;  as in a `LIKE` statement?   If `group` appears anywhere in the field?   Regular expression anchored to front or back?
Please give 1 or 2 example of output documents that show the shape you seek.

Comment: You can use [Projection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#std-label-find-projection) with _Aggregation Expression_ to filter array elements. Here is an example post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70587592/mongoose-projection-to-filter-list-not-working-but-native-does/71390824#71390824

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: { _id: BinData(3, "Uz+QwtoVMt7hjpqMrLxVhQ==") }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      permissions: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$permissions",
          as: "p",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              "$$p.context",
              { $regexMatch: { input: "$$p.key", regex: "group" } }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1A6viHDEquR)

---

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: BinData(3, "Uz+QwtoVMt7hjpqMrLxVhQ==")
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      permissions: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$permissions",
          as: "p",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {
                $not: [ "$$p.context" ]
              },
              {
                $regexMatch: {
                  input: "$$p.key",
                  regex: "group"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M34_HjRk_n2)

Comment: Thanks a lot! And I have one more question. How can I change condition to select only with WITHOUT `context` value (Situation `b`, which I had described before)? I have added `{ "$$p.context": {$exists: false} }` to `$and` array, but I have an error: `"errmsg" : "Invalid $set :: caused by :: Unrecognized expression '$$p.context'"`.

Comment: Here is my mongo query: https://mongoplayground.net/p/vqmAloaiJwO

Comment: @Shellai I update my answer